# How to pass the exception caught in inner catch to outer catch in a nested try catch

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am nesting try catches inside of a main try catch statement, what I would like to know is how I can make the main try catch fail if one of the nested try catches fails?

Here is my code:

```
try 
{    
    try 
    {
        //how can I make the main try catch fail if this try catch fails?
    } 
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        error_log();
    }       
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
    error_log();
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After `error_log();` in the first try-catch, type `throw $e;` (on a new line).  This will throw the error again, and the outer try-catch will handle it.

Answer (score 5):

You should extend Exception for the various different types of Exception. That way you can trigger a specific try-catch block:

```
try
{
  ...
  try
  {
    throwSomeException();
  }
  catch ( InnerException $e )
  {
    ...do stuff only for InnerException...
  }
  ...
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
  ...do stuff for all types of exception...
}
```

Additionally, you can chain your `catch` statements to trigger different blocks in a single try-catch:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch ( SpecificTypeOfException $e )
{
  ..do something specific
}
catch ( TypeOfException $e )
{
  ..do something less specific
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
  ..do something for all exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the inner catch, throw() - NOT recommended, I've seen several issues with PHP when doing this.  Or set a flag to throw just after the inner catch.

Here's an example throwing the same exception (or you could throw a different one).

```
try {
    $ex = null;
    try {
        //how can I make the main try catch fail if this try catch fails?
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $ex = $e;
        error_log();
    }

    if ($ex) {
       throw $ex;
    }

} catch(Exception $e){
    error_log();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I handle exceptions in a way similar to eventHandling in Javascript.
An event bubbles up the ladder from specific to generic. When it reaches the start program, an exception lost all it's meaning to the code and should simply be caught for logging and ending an application.

In the meantime a lot of stuff can happen

CallStack:

- Start Lunch
- Eat Apple (Before this code, an apple was bought as lunch)
- Sink teeth in apple

During my eating of the apple, a worm appeared:

```
throw NausiaException('I found a bleeding worm...');
```

Eat Apple scope catches

```
catch(Exception $e)
```

the exception because in that scope we can return the apple to the store and shout at the manager. Since nothing more useful can be said about the occurrence,

```
throw $e
```

is called because eating the apple failed.

**Something could've gone different**
However, if the store manager refused to refund, you can wrap the exception

```
throw new RefundFailedException('The manager is a cheap skate', RefundFailedException::REFUSED, $e)
```

**Start lunch Scope**
Start lunch scope wants to throw away bad lunch

```
try {
    //Start lunch
} catch (Exception $e) {
    switch (true) {
        case $e instanceof NausiaException:
        case $e instanceof RefundFailedException:
            //Throw lunch away
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use of a bool variable and "return" keyword at appropriate place could do the trick for you...

Comment: The point is to transfer control to the outer `catch` after running the inner one.  A `return` would skip it entirely.